# Creating embedded cells in XIB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently trying to create a table that will show the current downloads the user is downloading with a progress bar and details in each cell.

The project im working on is using xib and xib apparently does not support embedded sections in table views

```
Table views with embedded sections and cells are only supported in storyboard documents
```

Can I use Storyboard for a standalone UITableViewController? if so how?

Also is there a way around this for what im trying to do? If so how what would the workaround be?

Thanks in advance I have been stuck on this for the past couple of hours.

```
self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
ViewController1 *view2 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
TableViewController *view3 = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

view3.tabBarItem.title = @"Documents";
appWebView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
appWebView.title = @"Browser";
appWebView.tabBarItem.title = @"Browser";
view2.title = @"Downloads";
self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appWebView, view2, view3,  nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;
appWebView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Browser.png"];
view2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Download.png"];


 _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

[_window setRootViewController:appWebView];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
[_window addSubview:_rootController.view];
```

^^ is AppDelegate and below is the view i want to work with storyboard

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
TableViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
[sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:sfvc animated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: It's just as easy to make a standalone storyboard as it is to use a xib. Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html).

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    TableViewController *sfvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableViewController"];
    [sfvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:NO completion:nil];       Im getting this now "Warning: Attempt to present  on whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: I find it handy to put those first two lines in the view controller's init method.

Comment: What is self in this code? It should be something already in the view hierarchy if you are presenting with it.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Its the ViewController im trying to get working

Comment: A view controller should _never_ present itself. That goes against so many design principles. You need to return the controller and then have something else present it.

Comment: Just looked at your code again, all that code in viewDidLoad needs to come out. The first two lines can be put in the init method.

Comment: How could I set the controller to return when the tab on the tab bar is selected?

Comment: You instantiate a new one, then present it. I don't understand what's confusing you. You are doing some stuff in your code that doesn't make any sense. You should read some tutorials on how to programmatically present views.

Answer (score 1):

When you use table view in Xib(Base Xib). You have to create separate UITableViewCell. and you should register the UITableViewCell in the Base Xib View. Please follow the below code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    Yourtableview.register(UINib.init(nibName: "cellnibname", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can I use Storyboard for a standalone UITableViewController.
Drag the arrow (at the left side of firstView) to your table view and delete the original view(or just left there.

Also is there a way around this for what im trying to do? If so how what would the workaround be?
Delete the "tableView" under the tableViewDelegate in the xib file and add "tableView" once more. then every thing will be going alright.